# What does Docpad's @getBlock do?

Tags: docpad

This is a simple question that I'm having trouble finding an answer to. I'm just beginning to use [docpad](https://github.com/bevry/docpad) to build a site. I've encountered the following line in the HTML5 Boilerplate skeleton:

> `<%- @getBlock('styles').add(["/style.css"]).toHTML() %>`

Does anyone know what this does. The endpoint is that it outputs the following html:

> `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />`

But I'm unsure what is going on under the hood here and why this simple css link is produced in this manner rather.

Any illumination would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

After playing with this a bit, it seems that what @getBlock does is output a certain html code block. In this case, styles seems to specify the  code. What would be nice to know, if this is correct, is what other blocks there are in Docpad, or whatever other framework this @getBlock function(?) comes from...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Founder of DocPad here.

Correct, `getBlock` is part of the built in template helpers available to you. Several blocks are available, including `scripts`, `styles` and `meta`. The purpose of these is to allow plugins and other templates to safely inject and interact with the contents of the blocks.

Such examples could be:

- Adding a particular script to the header for only one template
- Minifying all the scripts you use, and even concatenating them into one file
- Injecting new scripts etc for certain plugins

We're working really hard at improving the documentation and support systems, so apologies that this stuff wasn't clear before - but we're doing our best!

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be any explanation of this on the DocPad website.

Comment: If someone could submit a pull request on our [docpad documentation repo](http://github.com/docpad/documentation) with their proposed changes of where this should go, that would be amazing!

Comment: now just coming back to this finally, what is still unclear to me from the documentation is how one goes about injecting content into one fo the built in blocks, such as meta...